# Computing the Lagrange multiplier in constrained optimization problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, quadratic-programming

As I know the value of the Lagrange multiplier does not have a valuable meaning in most cases. Our goal is to compute the values of the parameters.
Here is an example for constrained optimization: https://www.svm-tutorial.com/2016/09/duality-lagrange-multipliers/#comment-11576
$$\text{minimize }\; f(x,y)=x^2+y^2 ~\text{ s.t. }~  g(x,y)= x+y-1=0$$ 
He constructs the Lagrange multipliers and computes the value of $x$ and $y$. But at the end and after having the values of $x$ and $y$, he also computes the value of $\lambda$, which I don't understand **why**?
What it is the purpose to compute the value of $\lambda$? Why do we need its value at the very end?

Comment: Is $x+y-1=0$ given?

Comment: The equation and the constraint ($x+y-1$) are given.

Comment: What is your equation, i can not find any?

Comment: We want to minimize the function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ with the constraint $x+y-1=0$.

Comment: The constraint $x+y-1=0$?

Comment: $x+y-1$ not a constraint.  The constraint mentioned in your link is $x+y-1=0$.  In any case, the author is just being thorough.

Comment: @lulu So that means that we don't need to compute $\lambda$ and it does not have any usable value for us?

Comment: It is important to know that $\lambda$ exists.  In practice the numerical value for $\lambda $ has little or no meaning.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes, $x+y-1=0$ is the constraint. My bad

Comment: @lulu ok, thanks.

Comment: It doesn't matter, i have posted something for you.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner thanks. But by mentioning this sample I wanted to know, if we generally have to compute $\lambda$, if it is necessary at all and if computing $\lambda$ has some value for us

Comment: I would not agree, that Lagrange multipliers are of no interest on their own. In some applications they are just not needed.
For example in physics, the values of $\lambda$ is quite often meaningful. In classical mechanics with constraints, Lagrange multipliers help to compute, which forces appear to make the trajectory satisfy the constraint. In elasticity and fluid dynamics, a Lagrange multiplier (for the incompressibility constraint) turns out to be the pressure variable. In optimization with inequalities, it is of interest, which Lagrange multipliers are zero or not! (KKT conditions)

Answer (score -1):

You can simplify your problem writing

$$f(x,1-x)=x^2+(1-x)^2$$
If we denote

$$g(x)=2x^2-2x+1$$
and with
$$g'(x)=4x-2$$ you will find your Minimum.
You can also consider

$$f(x,y)+\lambda(x-y-1)=F(x,y,\lambda)$$
$$\frac{\partial F(x,y,\lambda)}{\partial x}=2x+\lambda$$
$$\frac{\partial F(x,y,\lambda)}{\partial y}=2y+\lambda$$
$$\frac{\partial F(x,y,\lambda)}{\partial \lambda}=x+y-1$$